# Propagator in normal modes

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, time-evolution, propagator, normal-modes

I started with the Hamiltonian of coupled oscillators in a circular lattice(with  $m=\hbar=1$ and $x_{a+N}=x_{a}$)
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}\left[p_a^2+\omega^2 x_a^2+\Omega^2\left(x_a-a_{a+1}\right)\right]$$
Then I used the normal-modes
$$\tilde{x}_k\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(-\frac{2\pi i k}{N}a\right)x_a\quad \tilde{p}_k\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi ik}{N}a\right)p_k$$ to 'decouple' the oscillators:
$$H=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(|\tilde{p_k}|^2+\tilde{\omega_k}^2 |\tilde{x_k}|^2 \right)$$
where$$\tilde{\omega}_k=\omega^2+4\Omega^2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)$$
In terms of the normal-modes the wavefunction is
$$\psi_0\left(\tilde{x_0},\tilde{x_1},..\right)=\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{\tilde{\omega}_k}{\pi}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\tilde{\omega}_k|\tilde{x}_k|^2\right)$$
Now, I want to time evolve this state by using the product of propagators of free-oscillators. If $\tilde{x}_k$ were real, then I would proceed with the propagator as
$$K\left(\tilde{x}_0,\tilde{x}_1,..;\tilde{x}'_0,\tilde{x}'_1;t\right)=\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\sqrt{\frac{\tilde{\omega}_k}{2\pi i \sin\left(\tilde{\omega}_k t\right)}}\exp\left[\frac{i\tilde{\omega}_k}{2 \sin\left(\tilde{\omega}_kt\right)}\{\left(\tilde{x_k}^2+\tilde{x_k}'^2\right)\cos\left(\tilde{\omega}_kt\right)-2\tilde{x}_k\tilde{x}'_k\}\right]$$
And I would time evolve the state $\psi_0$ as
$$\psi_1 \left(\tilde{x_0},\tilde{x_1},..;t\right) =\int d\tilde{x}'_0 d\tilde{x}'_1.. K\left(\tilde{x}_0,\tilde{x}_1,..;\tilde{x}'_0,\tilde{x}'_1...;t\right) \psi_0\left(\tilde{x_0},\tilde{x_1},..\right) $$
How can I find the propagator knowing that $\tilde{x}_k$ is not real and then find the time evolved state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change-of-variables question. In principle, you know how to evaluate the last integral in terms of one set of variables, the $x_a$. However, it would be easier to evaluate it in terms of the $\tilde{x}_k$.

The original integral is over $x_a \in \mathbb{R}^N$, so you need to figure out the corresponding region of (complex) $\tilde{x}_k$-space. A Fourier transform property comes in handy: The $x_a$ are real if and only if $\tilde{x}_{-k} = \tilde{x}_{k}^*$. We can thus integrate over the whole complex plane for only nonnegative values of $k$. `

We also need to incorporate the Jacobian of the transformation. The discrete Fourier transform is unitary with the normalization you chose, so the Jacobian is just $1$.